# Fetch the value of the selected options in Drop Down in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, dropdown, selected

I have a dropdown here in my edit view ,I am maintaining the data in my database by "value"(1 and 0) but would like to show it in the dropdown as "Active" and "Deactive")I would like to indicate the selected option , but its not working :
here is the view:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4" onChange="myNewFunction(this);" >
               <label for="pwd">Status</label>
             <select  class="form-control" id="Status" placeholder="Status" name="Status"  >
              <!-- <option value="">Select Status</option>  -->
                 <option value="1" >Active</option>
                <option value="0" >Deactive</option>
             </select>
             <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('Status'); ?> </div> 
            </div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
   var conceptName = $('#Status').find(":selected").text();
    //alert(conceptName);  
    var el = document.getElementById('Status');
    var text = el.options[el.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
     ($.trim($("#Status").children("option:selected").text()));
```

alert(conceptName); => results: the first option of select always

currently I am able to get the innerHTML, but not selected option.

Comment: No , I have tried all the answers there already

Comment: You are not setting it to any variable, and there is no ajax in your code.

Comment: have added var conpetName but its not working

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Can you please explain in code what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make comments yet but if your edit form is populated from PHP you can do something like this:

```php
<option value="1"<?php if ($status == 1) echo " selected";?>>Active</option>
<option value="0"<?php if ($status == 0) echo " selected";?>>Deactive</option>
```

Replace $status with the variable that contains the status value from your DB.

Comment: Solved  thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

From

```
var conceptName = $('#Status').find(":selected").text();
```

To

```
var conceptName = $('#Status option:selected').text();
```

Try it, will surely work.

Comment: still not working and ,alert(conceptName);  just give the first option always, I am maintaining the data by value 1and 0, does that cause the problem?

Comment: look at this fiddle..https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/xybethn2/8/

Comment: Dont need onchange(), this is a edit form , so basically I am getting the data from database which are (1 and 0), and just based on that want to show the selected option on the dropdown

Comment: in this scenario you should use if else condition in html file, your html code is not look like edit purpose code at first sight.